# Visual Studio 2013 debugger in Google Chrome not loading updated HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2013

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013. The problem that I have run into is that when I want to test my HTML/CSS in Google Chrome, it is leaving out a part of the HTML. The header worked fine and appears, but everything in my div wrapper is not loading into the localhost URL.

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="infoBar">
                <ul id="infoList">
                    <li class="infoItem">508-995-9695</li>
                    <li class="infoItem">13 Ventura Drive</li>
                    <li class="infoItem">North Dartmouth, MA</li>
                    <li class="infoItem">02747</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h1>Marmelo Bros. Construction</h1>
            <p>"Premier Construction & Masonry"</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="navBar">
                <ul id="navList">
                    <li class="navItem">Home</li>
                    <li class="navItem">About Us</li>
                    <li class="navItem">Portfolio</li>
                    <li class="navItem">Contact Us</li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, when I open it up in chrome and press F12, only this much is displayed... leaving out the wrapper and my navigation bar.

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="infoBar">
                <ul id="infoList">
                    <li class="infoItem">508-995-9695</li>
                    <li class="infoItem">13 Ventura Drive</li>
                    <li class="infoItem">North Dartmouth, MA</li>
                    <li class="infoItem">02747</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h1>Marmelo Bros. Construction</h1>
            <p>"Premier Construction & Masonry"</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

So just to clarify, the issue is not that my navigation bar isn't displaying, but that the HTML code for it isn't even loading.

I would be very intrigued to learn what simple mistake I made to cause this error.

Comment: I would just make sure that the page in question has been saved, and then try reloading it in the browser. Maybe try hitting Ctrl + F5 on the page to reload it as well (the browser might be caching an older version of the page or something weird). FWIW I was able to paste your HTML in a test page in VS 2013 and it was displayed fine.

Comment: Adding to what temarsden said, if the inspector is open in google chrome you can right click on the refresh button and you have the option to 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'. You will **only** be able to do this when the inspector is open.